# Sleep issues on Early 2008 Macbook Pro

Tags: hardware, suspend, macintosh

I'm a first time elementary OS user and have had few issues with it and it is by far my favorite Linux.  However, I cannot put my machine to sleep by closing the lid, or rather, I cannot wake it up as the screen that comes up upon waking is shredded and torn (distorted, in the frame buffer) and I cannot break out of X to get to a command line. Thus every time I put the machine to sleep I have to do a dirty shutdown and go through a disk check when I restart, which, in turn, I'm not even sure I'm doing right, so I touch /forcefsck and reboot again.

Is there a configuration setting I can change to avoid this issue?

Comment: I had this issue, disabling nvidia graphics card from bios resolved this issue